# Chef Windows: Create the home directory when creating Windows User

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying the below code to create a user and automatically create the home directory

```
user "username" do 
   supports :manage_home => true
   comment "ChefUser"
   home "C:\\Users\\username"
   password "somepassword"
   action :create
end
```

Below code also doesn't worked. It gave error `"Error: NoMethodError: undefined method each_char for #array:0x4434`

```
user "username" do 
   supports :manage_home => true
   comment "ChefUser"
   home "C:\\Users\\username"
   password "somepassword"
   action :create
   provider Chef::Provider::User::Useradd
end
```

What I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soundslike XY problem there.

I suspect you wish to create the use directory to set in some settings or documents for your users.

In windows the actual way to accomplish this is to work with `default user` and `all users` home dirs.

The content of `All Users` will be merged with each users directory on the workstation (i.e: a shortcut placed in `All Users\Desktop` will be on each user desktop and they can't delete it, usefull for support link or other parts shared by all users)

The content of `Default User` is the User home Template, at the first connection of a user , this user home directory will be created by copying the content of what is in `Default User` directory (including shortcuts on desktop, documents in the my document dir, etc.)

So the answer for your case is more to work on the `Default User` or `All Users` path than trying to create and work on each User Home dir. If there's scripts you wish to set there specific to each user, use `%USERNAME%` and `%USERPROFILE%` in thoose scripts to get the username and it's profiles diretory.

Answer (score 2):

To quote [to documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html#supported-features):

> When the Windows provider is used, Microsoft Windows does not create a
>   home directory for a user until that user logs on for the first time;
>   specifying the home directory does not have any effect as to where
>   Microsoft Windows ultimately places the home directory.

Comment: Ya I read that ... but I am not giving the provider as Chef::Provider::User::Useradd.

Comment: That provider will only work on Linux, specifically Linux distros that use `useradd` for adding users. Hence the name.

Comment: Ok I tried manually creating the directory and that is giving me permission error. Any workaround to create the directory. Thanks for you help

Comment: Again, please read what I quoted. Creating the home dir is done when the user first logs in, you cannot do it before then because that's not how Windows users work. If it makes you feel better, the home dir is also not used for much so it isn't a huge deal.